# ItemDecoration methods getting called with old views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a ListAdapter and I have added an ItemDecoration to the RecyclerView, The problem is when I remove an item from the list and update the list using ListAdapter's `submitList` method, The ItemDecoration methods like `getItemOffsets` and `onDraw` are getting called with old views whereas the adapter has already changed. I tried to detect these cases using the `hasPendingAdapterUpdates` method but I've had no luck with it since it's returning false even though the adapter and RecyclerView state are completely different.

```
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    if (parent.hasPendingAdapterUpdates()) {
      return
    }
    // getItemOffsets implementation
```

[image: Debugger Info]

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead it will give you this method to override i.e

```
 override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(ItemDecoration())
    }
```

And

```
override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(decoration)
}
```